# Why can a set of edges of a bipartite graph with maximum degree d be partitioned in d matchings ?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In Wikipedia I read this:
'If there is a perfect matching, then both the matching number and the edge cover number are |V| / 2.'
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29
Is this the reason why the partition is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

- First suppose that the graph is $d$-regular. Hall's theorem shows that the graph contains a perfect matching. Remove it and continue.
- In the general case, you can complete the graph into a $d$-regular graph by adding edges and possibly vertices. The augmented graph can be partitioned into $d$ perfect matchings. After you remove the added edges and vertices, you get $d$ matchings partitioning the original graph.